# Is it in appropriate to use the br tag multiple times to create a navigation menu? What would be a better alternative?

Tags: html, css

I have focused on learning a lot of backend coding, and I'm somewhat unfamiliar with current best practices of front end design. Back in the 1990's, I remember using the `<br>` tag whenever I needed a line break on my Geocities website. Today, I feel like this is probably frowned upon. I have the following navigation menu on my current page, and while it works just fine, I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this. There are no attributes assigned to the menu class in the CSS file.

```
nav#mainNav Navigation
        .menu
            a(href="/")
                i.fa.fa-ship
                |  All Ships
            br
            br
            a(href="/addreview")
                i.fa.fa-plus
                |  Add Review
            br
            br
            a(href="/topships")
                i.fa.fa-trophy
                |  Top Rated Ships
            br
            br
            a(href="/cabins")
                i.fa.fa-bed
                |  Best Cabins
            br
            br
            a(href="/bestdining")
                i.fa.fa-beer
                |  Best Dining
            br
            br
            a(href="/worstships")
                i.fa.fa-thumbs-down
                |  Lowest Rated Ships
            br
            br
            a(href="/recentreviews")
                i.fa.fa-rss-square
                |  Most Recent Reviews
            br
            br
            if user
                a(href="/me")
                    i.fa.fa-user
                    |  My Account
            
            br
            br
            p Coming Soon
            br
            br
            a(href="/kids")
                i.fa.fa-child
                |  Best For Kids
            br
            br
            a(href="/value")
                i.fa.fa-dollar
                |  Best Value
            br
            br
            a(href="/newships")
                i.fa.fa-anchor
                |  New Ships
            br
            br
            a(href="/addship")
                i.fa.fa-upload
                |  Add Ship
            br
            br
            a(href="/entertainment")
                i.fa.fa-film
                |  Best Entertainment
```

Comment: This is more opinion based than anything, but adding a padding or margin bottom would be a better alternative, I think.

Answer (score 1):

It is kinda frowned upon because there are some more elegant solutions that adapt better to different views (being responsive). With the br tag you are hard-coding a line break. Also, now there is something called semantic HTML. A lot of tags are used for accesibility. There are `<section> <nav>` and a lot of different tags that are used to divide the content of a site semantically. To do a "modern" design you should use a `<nav>` tag and inside a list `<ul>` with `<li>` elements inside. Then you style it with flexbox. It can be a little overwheling but I'm adding a link for an example.

[menu codepen](https://codepen.io/jorgemb76/pen/gNZqjm)

[Here's a guide to flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

You could try a framework to try to smooth out the learning curve. They do a lot of the heavy lifting for you. Bootstrap is a good place to start.

[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/)